# Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request - FCM HTTP v1 API via PHP

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im Trying to send notification through FCM HTTP v1 API, currently testing on localhost, downloaded private key file for service account "Firebase admin SDK" but im getting the following error:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

Code:

```
$serviceAccountKeyFile = 'C:\Users\Yaz\Downloads\<projectName>-f8312-65996b5966ea.json';
$fcmsendUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectName>-f8312/messages:send';

$notificationMessage = [
    "message" => [
        "token" => "fH8TwZfXQniUvF6aYqbTOu:APA91bH-uLHe3-e9-3N_Szu6bHwKbA4voAog1mzTVbOyFDUGjwZpZe8XUB2-FF0YD2StieCdvU1gtmNN4cg-ILyb6DFh1SrZhBfHZkMQUcPc6FsINaE38iLq8xhG-ankRPE0ifVmEDij",
        "notification" => [
            "title" => "Your Notification Title",
            "body" => "Your Notification Body"
        ]
    ]
];

$jsonMessage = json_encode($notificationMessage);

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . file_get_contents($serviceAccountKeyFile),
    'Content-Type: application/json; UTF-8',
];

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init($fcmsendUrl);

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonMessage);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
// Execute cURL session
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

of course i replaced < projectName >

i tried:

1. GuzzleHttp and got php error "Bearer ..." is not a valid header
2. creating another service account and using its private key

Comment: Try replacing `'Content-Type: application/json; UTF-8'` with `'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: @RobEyre Nothing changed.